# SQL Server : split row values into columns, multiple sets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched the questions, not finding an exact answer to mye specific question.

I have a table with these values:

```
Case    Milestone   Sorting Date
1       A           1       A1  
1       B           2       B2  
1       A           3       A3  
1       B           4       B4  
2       A           1       A1  
3       A           1       A1  
3       B           2       B2
```

Basically I would like to go through the rows and move the date to the corresponding column; Milestone A goes to column A with value = date. The problem is that I have multiple sets of cases with identical milestones. Sorting should be used to determine which milestones belong to which case.

The end result should be this:

```
Case    A   B       
1       A1  B2 
1       A3  B4
2       A1  
3       A1  B2
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thank you very much,

Kjell

Comment: You know how many times this question has been answered in SO. Search for `PIVOT` or `Cross tab`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Write as:

```
select * from 
( select [Case],Milestone,[Date],
         row_number() over (partition by [Case],Milestone 
         order by Sorting) as rownum
  from Test )
  as T
  pivot 
  ( max([Date]) 
    for Milestone in ([A],[B])
   ) as PVT
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2a84f/5)</kbd>

[Update]
You can write dynamic pivot as :

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Milestone)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Milestone FROM Test) AS T
--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery =     
'select [Case], ' + @ColumnName + ' from 
( select [Case],Milestone,[Date],
         row_number() over (partition by [Case],Milestone 
         order by Sorting) as rownum
  from Test )
  as T
  pivot 
  ( max([Date]) 
    for Milestone in (' + @ColumnName + ')
   ) as PVT
   order by [Case] asc' 

 --Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2a84f/7)</kbd>